# Nuxt3 and Firebase Cloud Function Hosting: How to access private key in .env file?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt3 app that is using "server routes" to create backend APIs to use for the front-end.

I have the following server route:

`server/api/imagekit/deleteFile.js`:

```js
import ImageKit from 'imagekit'

const imagekit = new ImageKit({
  publicKey: useRuntimeConfig().public.imagekitPublicKey,
  privateKey: useRuntimeConfig().imagekitPrivateKey,
  urlEndpoint: useRuntimeConfig().public.imagekitBaseURL
})

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  // Purge cache of file from Imagekit
  // See detailed email from Rahul @ imagekit dated aug 31, 2022
  const body = await useBody(event)

  const response = await imagekit.purgeCache(body.url)
  return response
})
```

**The above code works fine locally,** but once I deploy to Firebase Hosting, I get the following server error when trying to access the API `deleteFile`:

```js
description: ""
message: "Missing privateKey during ImageKit initialization"
statusCode: 500
statusMessage: "Internal Server Error"
url: "/api/imagekit/deleteFile"
```

In case it's relevant to this question, here is my code for Nuxt's `nuxt.config.ts` file where the `runtimeConfig` property is listed:

```js
    runtimeConfig: {

        imagekitPrivateKey: '',
        public: {
            baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://example.com' : 'http://localhost:3000',
            imagekitBaseURL: 'https://ik.imagekit.io/example/',
            imagekitPublicKey: 'public_AdZM6u2+FvznG/LngYp7Ab3TJy4='
        }
    }
```

Also, my `firebase.json` uses 2 codebases for the functions: one for server and one for cloud functions:

```js
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": ".output/server",
      "codebase": "nuxt"
    },
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "functions"
    }
  ],
  "hosting": [
    {
      "site": "XXX",
      "public": ".output/public",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "cleanUrls": true,
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "server"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I do have an `.env` file in project root that holds the imagekitPrivateKey value.

**How would I provide this information to Firebase hosting deployment so ImageKit properly initializes with the private key?**

Comment: Have you read through the firebase docs? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the variables from `.env` in `nuxt.config.ts` as shown below:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    // Uppercase preferred in .env file
    imagekitPrivateKey: process.env.IMAGEKIT_PRIVATE_KEY,
  },
});
```

Then you can access it in your API routes:

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const { imagekitPrivateKey } = useRuntimeConfig();

  return { message: "success" };
});
```

Comment: You use empty string instead of `process.env` like so: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/features/runtime-config#environment-variables . I dont 'think that is the issue here.

Comment: @redshift but have you tried it? Also there's no `.env` file in your `.output/server` after build i.e. the functions directory.

Comment: OK this was the right answer. First time I tried this, it didn't work. I tried it again and it works....thanks!